# Why are environment variables empty in Flask apps?

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

I have a flask app (my_app) that calls a function in a different file (my_function):

**my_app.py:**

```
from my_functions import my_function
@app.route('/')
def index():
    my_function()
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**my_functions.py:**

```
def my_function():
    try:
        import my_lib
    except:
        print("my_lib not found in system!")
    # do stuff...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_function()
```

When I execute my_functions.py directly (i.e., python my_functions.py) "my_lib" is imported without error; however, when I execute the flask app (i.e., python my_app.py) I get an import error for "my_lib".

When I print the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable at the beginning of each file:

```
print(os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'])
```

I get the correct value when calling my_functions.py, but get no value (empty) when calling my_app.py.Trying to set this value at the beginning of my_app.py has no effect:

```
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/usr/local/lib'
```

**Questions:**

(1) Why is 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' empty when called within the Flask app?

(2) How do I set it?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: is flask being executed as part of an apache directive?  Apache limits access to the environment variables (for a damn good reason, security purposes).  Anything you want available needs to be passed via an apache directive or directly in the wsgi script that is being executed.  This is how it is for django at least.

Comment: right now I am just executing the flask app directly. I'll ultimately be executing it through nginx/gunicorn, but for now I would like to get it running standalone. Might I need to set these variables in some flask wsgi config file?

Comment: well if it's being executed directly what is your command for executing it?  Environment variables just wouldn't be nor should be passed into a web application, that's dangerous and security prone.  If you are executing it directly it may be calling a special development mode, which means you need to set your lib on the python path or something that WOULD be imported.

Comment: I'm executing it from the shell: python my_app.py. That's a good suggestion to look for how variables are imported in Flask. I'll look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is cleared when executing the flask app, likely for security reasons as Mike suggested.

To get around this, I use subprocess to make a call directly to an executable:

```
import subprocess
call_str = "executable_name -arg1 arg1_value -arg2 arg2_value"
subprocess.call(call_str, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Ideally the program should be able to use the python bindings, but for now calling the executable works.

Comment: Wanted to know if this worked. Also, what should be the value of call_str if my ld_library_path = '/usr/local/lib' ?