# Deploy Tensorflow on a web server with Flask

Tags: apache, flask, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to deploy a Flask web app with tensorflow on an AWS server ( AMI ID: Deep Learning (ami-77e0da1d)), for an image classification app.

When I use tensorflow in the server, it works normally, but when I try to use it with the app, I get:

> No data received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

In the end of the error.log file, I have:

> F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:204] could not find cudnnCreate in cudnn DSO; dlerror: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: cudnnCreate
>   [Sat May 14 11:30:54.124034 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1332:tid 139695334930304] AH00051: child pid 2999 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

My CuDNN version: 4.0.7

I can provide more details if necessary

Comment: What's the value of your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable? It looks like TensorFlow is unable to find the CUDA libraries....

Comment: it is /usr/local/cuda/lib64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by deploying on a CPU instead of a GPU, and it was enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is being cleared before starting your web app starts, for security reasons. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28712022/3574081), which observes that the value of `os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']` is empty inside the Flask app, even though it may be set when you launch Apache.

There are at least a couple of options:

- You could use Apache's [`mod_env`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html) to set the environment variables that are propagated to your Flask app.
- Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28756047/3574081), you could modify your script to perform a `subprocess` call, and set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` for the subprocess.